# basic vocabulary list

Tags: vocabulary

A long time ago, when I was in school they told me that basic vocabulary has 2000 words. I'm not sure about the number but I'm very interested about the list.

Do you have any idea where can I find a list with the basic vocabulary words?

Comment: Charles Ogdon reckoned it could be done with 850 words. See here: http://ogden.basic-english.org/words.html

Comment: Here's [one list of a thousand](http://splasho.com/upgoer5/phpspellcheck/dictionaries/1000.dicin). I doubt very much there's a single authoritative list, but there are probably a few you could find with a search engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [*Nolls' Top 3,000 American English Words*](http://www.manythings.org/vocabulary/lists/l/noll-about.php) list compiled by Paul and Bernice Noll, taking forty newspapers and magazines, sorting the words and then counting the frequency of the words.

Someone says that if you learn the most common 3000 words in your target language, you will be able to understand 80% of the language. Of course, the statement is not strict.